# List of list with conditionals

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a list of lists returning specific numbers.

```
def game(height):
    lstoflst = []
    sublist = []
    for row in range(height):
        sublist.append(row)
        if len(sublist)>2:
            sublist.remove(sublist[0])
            lstoflst.append(list(sublist))
    return lstoflst
```

Output: `[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9]]`

Desired Output: `[[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[0,2],[1,2],[2,2],[0,3],[1,3],[2,3],[3,3]]`

I'm confused if I need to add conditionals to make this work and if so, how would I implement it into my code.

Comment: Any time you find yourself defining a list to which you then append items in a `for` loop, ask yourself whether a list comprehension would be cleaner instead.  Your desired output can be obtained with `output = [[x, xmax] for xmax in range(4) for x in range(xmax+1)]`

Comment: @jez Thanks for the advice, but to visualize step by step how the list of list works, how would it be if it wasn't compressed? I'm fairly new to python and wanted to see how it works. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @jez

```
n = 4
[[x, xmax] for xmax in range(n) for x in range(xmax+1)]
```

`[[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[0,2],[1,2],[2,2],[0,3],[1,3],[2,3],[3,3]]`

Without a list comprehension,
you can print along the way

```
lst = []
for xmax in range(n):
    #print(lst)
    for x in range(xmax+1):
        #print(lst)
        lst.append([x, xmax])
```

Comment: How would this be in a step by step process? I'm fairly new to python and wanted to see visually how it works.

Comment: added code without list comprehension so you can work through it

Comment: @JonRichardson as for “compressed”, note that it isn’t much. The list comprehension version eliminates the characters `lst.append()` and two colons.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to perform an inner loop:

```
def game(height):
    lstoflst = []
    sublist = []
    for row in range(height):
        for second_row in range(height):
          
            insert_into_sublist(row)
            insert_into_sublist(second_row)

    return lstoflst.sort()

def insert_into_sublist(element_to_insert, sublist, lstoflst):

    sublist.append(element_to_insert)

    if len(sublist) == 2:
        lstoflst.append(list(sublist))
        sublist.clear()
        sublist.append(second_row)
```